how can i make functions work inside a modal?
I am working on a script for work and halfway through writing my code, i changed my code to pull up a majority of my HTML in a modal. My problem is that i have already made a lot of functions that now wont work with the content in the modal. I want to try to make my functions work with the modal by changing as little as possible, but im afraid im going to have to rewrite all the code.
here is my code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Zoho Desk - Apps</title>
    <style>
      .hidden {
        display: none;
      }
      .container {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: left;
        align-items: flex-start;
      }
      .content {
        flex: 1;
      }
      .sidebar {
        flex: 0 0 60px;
        position: fixed;
        right: 20px;
      }
      ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        padding: 0;
      }
      li {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
      }
      li button {
        margin-left: 10px;
      }
      .popup {
        position: fixed;
        left: 50%;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        padding: 20px;
        background-color: white;
        border: 1px solid black;
        box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        z-index: 1000;
      }
      .overlay {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        z-index: 999;
      }
      .img {
        right: 20px;
        bottom: 0;
        position: fixed;
      }
      .grid-container {
        display: grid;
        gap: 10px;
      }
      .grid-container > div {
        display: none; /* Hide all divs initially */
      }
      .grid-container > div:not(.hidden) {
        display: grid;
        gap: 10px;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
      }
      .grid-container > div:not(.hidden) button {
        display: grid;
        gap: 10px;
      }
      .Btn {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        flex-grow: 1;
        background-color: aliceblue;
        color: black;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        padding: 1px;
        border: 2px solid dimgray;
        font-family: "Times New Roman", serif;
        text-align: center;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
      }
      .Btn:hover {
        background-color: lightslategrey;
        color: white;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a
      target="_blank"
      href="http://helpdesk.wiki.clacorp.com/index.php/Main_Page"
    >
      <img class="img" src="/app/img/img2.png" alt="Wiki" />
    </a>
    <button id="openModalBtn">Open Modal</button>
    <div id="popup" class="popup hidden">
      <div id="popupContent"></div>
      <button onclick="closePopup2()">Close</button>
    </div>
    <div id="overlay" class="overlay hidden" onclick="closePopup2()"></div>
    <script src="https://js.zohostatic.com/support/developer_sdk/v1/js/ZohoDeskClientSDK.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      function openPopupInNewWindow() {
        const newWindow = window.open(
          "",
          "Popup",
          "width=" + screen.width + ",height=" + screen.height
        );
        if (newWindow) {
          newWindow.document.write(`
                    <style>
                        .hidden {
                            display: none;
                        }
                    </style>
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="content">
                            <input type="text" id="callerName" placeholder="Caller Name"><br>
                            <input type="text" id="EquipmentName" placeholder="Equipment with issue"><br>
                            <input type="text" id="SymptomName" placeholder="Symptoms of Device"><br>
                            <input type="text" id="IssueName" placeholder="Issue"><br>
                            <select id="dropdown" onchange="showOptionsDiv()">
                                <option value=""></option>
                                <optgroup label="PC">
                                    <option value="Cookies">Cookie Bake</option>
                                    <option value="Monitor issues">Monitor issues</option>
                                    <option value="Taskbar Gone">Taskbar Gone</option>
                                    <option value="EFI Shell">EFI Shell Error</option>
                                    <option value="Proxy">Proxy Issue</option>
                                    <option value="Cache">Cache Issue</option>
                                    <option value="NewPC">New PC Setup</option>
                                </optgroup>
                                <optgroup label="Router/Modem">
                                    <option value="Site Down">Site Down</option>
                                    <option value="ISP">ISP</option>
                                    <option value="4G">4G card</option>
                                    <option value="Crash Pack">Crash Pack</option>
                                </optgroup>
                                <optgroup label="VOIP Phones">
                                    <option value="Forward">Forward Calls</option>
                                    <option value="Phone Issues">Connection Issues</option>
                                </optgroup>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="sidebar">
                            <ul id="optionsList"></ul>
                            <button onclick="generateBulletedList()">Generate Bulleted List</button>
                            <button onclick="window.close()">Close</button>      
                        </div>
                    </div>
                `);
          popup.classList.remove("hidden");
          overlay.classList.remove("hidden");
        } else {
          console.error("Popup elements not found.");
        }
      }
      function closePopup() {
        window.close();
      }
      // Add your existing JavaScript functions here (showOptionsDiv, addItemToList, etc.)
    </script>
    <script>
      document
        .getElementById("openModalBtn")
        .addEventListener("click", function () {
          openPopupInNewWindow();
        });

      document
        .getElementById("callerName")
        .addEventListener("keypress", function (e) {
          if (e.key === "Enter") {
            const callerName = document
              .getElementById("callerName")
              .value.trim();
            if (callerName !== "") {
              addItemToList(callerName, true, "Caller: ", "callerOptionsList");
              document.getElementById("callerName").value = "";
            }
          }
        });

      document
        .getElementById("EquipmentName")
        .addEventListener("keypress", function (e) {
          if (e.key === "Enter") {
            const EquipmentName = document
              .getElementById("EquipmentName")
              .value.trim();
            if (EquipmentName !== "") {
              addItemToList(
                EquipmentName,
                true,
                "Equipment: ",
                "equipmentOptionsList"
              );
              document.getElementById("EquipmentName").value = "";
            }
          }
        });

      document
        .getElementById("SymptomName")
        .addEventListener("keypress", function (e) {
          if (e.key === "Enter") {
            const SymptomName = document
              .getElementById("SymptomName")
              .value.trim();
            if (SymptomName !== "") {
              addItemToList(
                SymptomName,
                true,
                "Symptoms: ",
                "SymptomOptionsList"
              );
              document.getElementById("SymptomName").value = "";
            }
          }
        });

      document
        .getElementById("IssueName")
        .addEventListener("keypress", function (e) {
          if (e.key === "Enter") {
            const IssueName = document.getElementById("IssueName").value.trim();
            if (IssueName !== "") {
              addItemToList(IssueName, true, "Issue: ", "IssueOptionsList");
              document.getElementById("IssueName").value = "";
            }
          }
        });

      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
        setupEventListeners();
      });

      function setupEventListeners() {
        addEnterKeyEventListener("callerName", "Caller: ", "callerOptionsList");
        addEnterKeyEventListener(
          "EquipmentName",
          "Equipment: ",
          "equipmentOptionsList"
        );
        addEnterKeyEventListener(
          "SymptomName",
          "Symptoms: ",
          "SymptomOptionsList"
        );
        addEnterKeyEventListener("IssueName", "Issue: ", "IssueOptionsList");
        document
          .getElementById("dropdown")
          .addEventListener("change", showOptionsDiv);
      }

      function addEnterKeyEventListener(inputId, staticText, listId) {
        const inputElement = document.getElementById(inputId);
        if (inputElement) {
          inputElement.addEventListener("keypress", function (e) {
            if (e.key === "Enter") {
              const inputValue = inputElement.value.trim();
              if (inputValue !== "") {
                addItemToList(inputValue, true, staticText, listId);
                inputElement.value = "";
              }
            }
          });
        } else {
          console.error(`Element with ID '${inputId}' not found.`);
        }
      }

      function showOptionsDiv() {
        const selectedOption = document.getElementById("dropdown").value;
        const optionsDiv = document.getElementById("optionsDiv");
        if (!optionsDiv) {
          console.error("Element with ID 'optionsDiv' not found.");
          return;
        }
        const divs = optionsDiv.querySelectorAll("div");
        divs.forEach(function (div) {
          div.classList.add("hidden");
        });
        if (selectedOption) {
          const divToShow = document.getElementById(selectedOption + "Div");
          if (divToShow) {
            optionsDiv.classList.remove("hidden");
            divToShow.classList.remove("hidden");
          } else {
            console.error(`Element with ID '${selectedOption}Div' not found.`);
          }
        } else {
          optionsDiv.classList.add("hidden");
        }
      }

      function addOptionToList(selectId, optionId) {
        const select = document.getElementById(selectId);
        if (!select) {
          console.error(`Element with ID '${selectId}' not found.`);
          return;
        }
        const selectedOption = select.options[select.selectedIndex];
        const optionText = selectedOption.text;
        const optionValue = selectedOption.value;
        const listItem = document.createElement("li");
        listItem.textContent = optionText;
        listItem.setAttribute("value", optionValue);
        listItem.setAttribute("id", optionId);
        addButtonsToListItem(listItem, optionText);
        const optionsList = document.getElementById("optionsList");
        if (optionsList) {
          optionsList.appendChild(listItem);
        } else {
          console.error("Element with ID 'optionsList' not found.");
        }
      }

      let firstItemAdded = false;

      function addCustomOptionToList() {
        const staticText = "- ";
        const customOption = prompt("Enter custom option:");
        if (customOption !== null && customOption !== "") {
          const listItem = document.createElement("li");
          listItem.textContent = staticText + customOption;
          addButtonsToListItem(listItem, customOption);
          const optionsList = document.getElementById("optionsList");
          if (optionsList) {
            if (!firstItemAdded) {
              const troubleshootingSteps = document.createElement("li");
              troubleshootingSteps.textContent = "Troubleshooting Steps:";
              optionsList.appendChild(troubleshootingSteps);
              firstItemAdded = true;
            }
            optionsList.appendChild(listItem);
          } else {
            console.error("Element with ID 'optionsList' not found.");
          }
        }
      }

      function Transfer() {
        const staticText = "Transferred Calls From ";
        let customOption1 = prompt("From Site:");
        ZOHODESK.set("ticketForm.cf_site_transferring_from", {
          value: customOption1,
        });
        if (customOption1 !== null && customOption1 !== "") {
          let customOption2 = prompt("To site:");
          ZOHODESK.set("ticketForm.cf_site_transferring_to", {
            value: customOption2,
          });
          if (customOption2 !== null && customOption2 !== "") {
            const listItem = document.createElement("li");
            listItem.textContent =
              staticText + customOption1 + " to " + customOption2;
            addButtonsToListItem(
              listItem,
              customOption1 + "  " + customOption2
            );
            const optionsList = document.getElementById("optionsList");
            if (optionsList) {
              optionsList.appendChild(listItem);
            } else {
              console.error("Element with ID 'optionsList' not found.");
            }
          }
        }
      }

      function vnc(option, isTextInput = false, staticText, listId) {
        const staticTextWithCustomOption = "- VNC into PC with IP: 10.30.";
        const staticTextWithoutCustomOption = "- VNC into PC";
        const customOption = prompt(
          "- VNC into PC              No input = No IP"
        );
        if (customOption !== null && customOption !== "") {
          const listItem = document.createElement("li");
          listItem.textContent = staticTextWithCustomOption + customOption;
          addButtonsToListItem(listItem, customOption);
          const optionsList = document.getElementById("optionsList");
          if (optionsList) {
            optionsList.appendChild(listItem);
          } else {
            console.error("Element with ID 'optionsList' not found.");
          }
        } else {
          const listItem = document.createElement("li");
          listItem.textContent = staticTextWithoutCustomOption;
          addButtonsToListItem(listItem, "");
          const optionsList = document.getElementById("optionsList");
          if (optionsList) {
            if (!firstItemAdded && !isTextInput) {
              const troubleshootingSteps = document.createElement("li");
              troubleshootingSteps.textContent = "Troubleshooting Steps:";
              optionsList.appendChild(troubleshootingSteps);
              firstItemAdded = true;
            }
            optionsList.appendChild(listItem);
          } else {
            console.error("Element with ID 'optionsList' not found.");
          }
        }
      }

      function Puttyip(option, isTextInput = false, staticText, listId) {
        const staticTextWithCustomOption = "- Putty into PC with IP: 10.30.";
        const staticTextWithoutCustomOption =
          "- Putty into PC              No input = No IP";
        const customOption = prompt("IP - 10.30. :");
        if (customOption !== null && customOption !== "") {
          const listItem = document.createElement("li");
          listItem.textContent = staticTextWithCustomOption + customOption;
          addButtonsToListItem(listItem, customOption);
          const optionsList = document.getElementById("optionsList");
          if (optionsList) {
            optionsList.appendChild(listItem);
          } else {
            console.error("Element with ID 'optionsList' not found.");
          }
        } else {
          const listItem = document.createElement("li");
          listItem.textContent = staticTextWithoutCustomOption;
          addButtonsToListItem(listItem, "");
          const optionsList = document.getElementById("optionsList");
          if (optionsList) {
            if (!firstItemAdded && !isTextInput) {
              const troubleshootingSteps = document.createElement("li");
              troubleshootingSteps.textContent = "Troubleshooting Steps:";
              optionsList.appendChild(troubleshootingSteps);
              firstItemAdded = true;
            }
            optionsList.appendChild(listItem);
          } else {
            console.error("Element with ID 'optionsList' not found.");
          }
        }
      }

      function addItemToList(option, isTextInput = false, staticText, listId) {
        const listItem = document.createElement("li");
        if (isTextInput) {
          listItem.textContent = staticText + option;
        } else {
          listItem.textContent = option;
        }
        addButtonsToListItem(listItem, option);
        const optionsList = document.getElementById("optionsList");
        if (optionsList) {
          if (!firstItemAdded && !isTextInput) {
            // need to add option to remove none from input fields
            const troubleshootingSteps = document.createElement("li");
            troubleshootingSteps.textContent = "Troubleshooting Steps:";
            optionsList.appendChild(troubleshootingSteps);
            firstItemAdded = true;
          }
          optionsList.appendChild(listItem);
        } else {
          console.error("Element with ID 'optionsList' not found.");
        }
      }

      function ispoutage(option, isTextInput = false, staticText, listId) {
        const listItem = document.createElement("li");
        if (isTextInput) {
          listItem.textContent = staticText + option;
        } else {
          listItem.textContent = option;
        }
        addButtonsToListItem(listItem, option);
        const optionsList = document.getElementById("optionsList");
        if (optionsList) {
          if (!firstItemAdded && !isTextInput) {
            const troubleshootingSteps = document.createElement("li");
            troubleshootingSteps.textContent = "Troubleshooting Steps:";
            optionsList.appendChild(troubleshootingSteps);
            firstItemAdded = true;
          }
          optionsList.appendChild(listItem);
        } else {
          console.error("Element with ID 'optionsList' not found.");
        }
        ZOHODESK.set("ticketForm.cf_outtage", { value: true });
      }

      function addButtonsToListItem(listItem, optionText) {
        const removeButton = document.createElement("button");
        removeButton.textContent = "Remove";
        removeButton.onclick = function () {
          listItem.remove();
        };
        listItem.appendChild(removeButton);

        const repeatButton = document.createElement("button");
        repeatButton.textContent = "Repeat";
        repeatButton.onclick = function () {
          repeatOption(optionText);
        };
        listItem.appendChild(repeatButton);

        const noteButton = document.createElement("button");
        noteButton.textContent = "Note";
        noteButton.onclick = function () {
          writeNoteInput(listItem);
        };
        listItem.appendChild(noteButton);
      }

      function writeNoteInput(listItem) {
        if (listItem.querySelector(".note-input")) {
          return;
        }
        const staticText = "";
        const noteInput = document.createElement("input");
        noteInput.type = "text";
        noteInput.placeholder = "Write your note here";
        noteInput.classList.add("note-input");

        const saveButton = document.createElement("button");
        saveButton.textContent = "Save Note";
        saveButton.onclick = function () {
          addNoteToItem(listItem, noteInput.value);
          noteInput.remove();
          saveButton.remove();
        };

        noteInput.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
          if (event.key === "Enter") {
            event.preventDefault();
            addNoteToItem(listItem, noteInput.value);
            noteInput.remove();
            saveButton.remove();
          }
        });

        listItem.appendChild(document.createTextNode(staticText));
        listItem.appendChild(noteInput);
        listItem.appendChild(saveButton);
      }

      function addNoteToItem(listItem, note) {
        if (note.trim() !== "") {
          let sublist = listItem.querySelector("ul");
          if (!sublist) {
            sublist = document.createElement("ul");
            listItem.appendChild(sublist);
          }
          const noteListItem = document.createElement("li");
          noteListItem.textContent = note;
          sublist.appendChild(noteListItem);
        }
      }

      function showPopupAndCopy(predefinedText) {
        const popup = document.getElementById("popup");
        const popupText = document.getElementById("popupText");
        if (popup && popupText) {
          popupText.textContent = predefinedText;
          popup.classList.remove("hidden");
          document.getElementById("overlay").classList.remove("hidden");
          navigator.clipboard
            .writeText(predefinedText)
            .then(() => {
              console.log("Text copied to clipboard");
            })
            .catch((err) => {
              console.error("Could not copy text: ", err);
            });
        } else {
          console.error("Popup elements not found.");
        }
      }

      function closePopup2() {
        const popup = document.getElementById("popup");
        if (popup) {
          popup.classList.add("hidden");
        } else {
          console.error("Element with ID 'popup' not found.");
        }
        const overlay = document.getElementById("overlay");
        if (overlay) {
          overlay.classList.add("hidden");
        } else {
          console.error("Element with ID 'overlay' not found.");
        }
      }

      function generateBulletedList() {
        const listItems = document.getElementById("optionsList").children;
        let nonBulletedList = "";
        for (let i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++) {
          const listItemText = listItems[i].childNodes[0].textContent.trim();
          nonBulletedList += listItemText + "\n";
          const sublistItems = listItems[i].querySelectorAll("ul > li");
          for (let j = 0; j < sublistItems.length; j++) {
            nonBulletedList +=
              "  -  " + sublistItems[j].textContent.trim() + "\n";
          }
          if (listItemText.startsWith("Caller:")) {
            nonBulletedList += "\n";
          }
          if (listItemText.startsWith("Equipment:")) {
            nonBulletedList += "\n";
          }
          if (listItemText.startsWith("Symptoms:")) {
            nonBulletedList += "\n";
          }
          if (listItemText.startsWith("Issue:")) {
            nonBulletedList += "\n";
          }
        }
        const textArea = document.createElement("textarea");
        textArea.value = nonBulletedList;
        document.body.appendChild(textArea);
        textArea.select();
        document.execCommand("copy");
        document.body.removeChild(textArea);
        alert("List copied to clipboard:\n\n" + nonBulletedList);
        ZOHODESK.set("ticketForm.description", { value: nonBulletedList });
      }

      function repeatOption(optionText) {
        const repeatedItem = document.createElement("li");
        repeatedItem.textContent = optionText + " again";
        addButtonsToListItem(repeatedItem, optionText);
        document.getElementById("optionsList").appendChild(repeatedItem);
      }

      ZOHODESK.invoke("RESIZE", { width: "455px", height: "545px" });

      App.instance.on("ticket.update", function (data) {
        //data gives the ticket details
      });

      window.onload = function () {
        ZOHODESK.extension.onload().then(function (App) {
          //Get ticket related data
          ZOHODESK.get("ticket.email")
            .then(function (res) {
              //response Handling
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
              //error Handling
            });
        });
      };

      // notes in description box
      //connect to clawsmachine to pull info and dump in description
    </script>
    <script src="./js/extension.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </body>
</html>


i have removed some of my html code to make it fit the character limit
i have tried placing the javascript within my modal but that broke all of my code, and i have tried looking for different ways to write the functions but i cant seem to find anything that makes the modal accept the functions

Please post a [mcve], minimal being the optimal word. No one is going to go through that much code to find out how to make it function on a modal. What do you actually expect it to do?

In general, your problem is the following:

you had some HTML
you have written some Javascript for that HTML
you moved that HTML into a bootstrap modal
Your Javascript won't work inside your Bootstrap modal

Since you have pasted way too much code into the question and you did not describe all your problems, from our point of view we would need to set up a test environment with your truncated code, test and guess what your exact expectations were. Since doing this would be outside the bounds of volunteer question answering, I will give you guidance for typical problems that could arise when you do something like this and the typical fix for these problems. If you find my answer too vague, then you will need to edit your question, narrow down the problem to be fixed to a single problem and notify me here in the comment-section. Without further ado, here are typical problems with moving content into a modal like this and the typical solution for those typical problems:
1. Context change
Your initial context was the entirety of your HTML but moving this as a context into a modal changed its context. So your stylings and Javascript code using selectors are no longer applying only to the content that you have put into the modal, but to elements outside the modal too.
Solution: Make sure you have a parent container for the HTML that you have moved into the modal and change all your selectors to be specifying the presence of such parents.
Example:


.container p {
    color: red;
}
<p>abc</p>
<div class="container">
    <p>def</p>
</div>
<p>ghi</p>



Note that I have specified that my styling is for descendants of .container so things outside of it are ignored.
2. Invalid HTML
If you are not using an iframe and you pasted this entire content into the iframe, including doctype, html tag, etc., then your HTML is not valid. Run an HTML validator on your page and fix any problems that invalidate your HTML
3. Events not firing
You defined events, like load events and stuff like that. Yet, your modal content is supposed to execute the load events upon modal open. So it's feasible to implement a function that is to do what needs to be done when the modal is opening and call it upon modal open. See Calling a function on Bootstrap modal open
